# Computing the average of two rows in r with rolling window

Tags: r, average, moving-average, price

So I have this dataset in which, between other columns I have price, made like this

```
  list(
    investor = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2),
    asset = c("x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "Y", "y", "y"),
    price = c(10, 12, 0, 0, 0 , 14, 23, 25, 0, 0, 20),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L)
)
```

I want R to change those zero in the price column by computing the average of the previous and next available number.

For example the third entry should be the average between 12 and 14, hence 13.

Then entry number four should then become the average between 13 and 14, and so on so forth.
So basically I want to substitute those zero with this type of computation.
I also think that a moving average function should be ok for those zero.
Please notice I have 6k different type of asset, hence I need to `group_by(asset)`

I'm a basic R user so I don't really have any idea on how to do this, but I would prefer a dplyr solution, since is the thing I'm more able to understand at the moment.

Comment: am not quite sure of your method. But try `df %>%
  group_by(asset = tolower(asset)) %>%
  mutate(price1 = zoo::na.approx(na_if(price, 0)))`

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't do exactly what you say, but potentially what you want. It does a linear interpolation between the numbers on either side of the 0s, so third number becomes 12.5 as it is filling 3 empty spots between 12 and 14 which I suspect is what you want, but there are options within `zoo` for different methods of filling the NAs. In your `Y` asset group there is no data to use for filling so I have left it as NA.

```r
library(zoo)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'zoo'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     as.Date, as.Date.numeric
  library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

test <-   data.frame(
  investor = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2),
  asset = c("x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "Y", "y", "y"),
  price = c(10, 12, 0, 0, 0 , 14, 23, 25, 0, 0, 20)
)
#set 0s to NAs as they are easier to fill
test = test %>% mutate(price = ifelse(price == 0, NA, price))

#use zoo::na.approx to fill
test = test %>% group_by(asset) %>% 
  mutate(price = zoo::na.approx(price,na.rm = F))

test
#> # A tibble: 11 x 3
#> # Groups:   asset [3]
#>    investor asset price
#>       <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#>  1        1 x      10  
#>  2        1 x      12  
#>  3        1 x      12.5
#>  4        2 x      13  
#>  5        2 x      13.5
#>  6        2 x      14  
#>  7        1 y      23  
#>  8        1 y      25  
#>  9        1 Y      NA  
#> 10        1 y      22.5
#> 11        2 y      20
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: isnt this what i posted in the comments 5 minutes ago? If so, maintain it but give credit, ie as posted in the comments by so and so...

Comment: Hi sorry, the comment definitely wasn't there when I started my response, I suppose you wrote it as I was typing but posted a lot quicker. I didn't mean to steal credit. I wasn't aware of the `na_if` function - looks handy thanks

Comment: Its fine. Its been more than 5 hours hahaha.  Will upvote these solutions

Comment: I mean it has been now when I saw your comment on this post. But when I made the answer it was the same time as your comment

Comment: my comment was 3 minutes earlier. 23:06:36Z vs 23:09:37Z

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a canned function that will do exactly what you want.  However, I wrote a function that would do that:

```r
library(tidyverse)
dat <-   data.frame(
  investor = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2),
  asset = c("x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y"),
  price = c(10, 12, 0, 0, 0 , 14, 23, 25, 0, 0, 20))

closest_nonmiss <- function(x){
  for(i in 1:length(x)){
    if(is.na(x[i])){
    w <- which(!is.na(x))
    i1 <- max(w[which(w < i)])
    i2 <- min(w[which(w > i)])
    x[i] <- mean(x[c(i1,i2)])
    }
  }
  x
}
```

Here is how it would work:

```r
dat %>% 
  group_by(asset) %>%
  mutate(price = case_when(price == 0 ~ NA_real_, 
                           TRUE ~ price)) %>% 
  mutate(price = closest_nonmiss(price))
#> # A tibble: 11 × 3
#> # Groups:   asset [2]
#>    investor asset price
#>       <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#>  1        1 x      10  
#>  2        1 x      12  
#>  3        1 x      13  
#>  4        2 x      13.5
#>  5        2 x      13.8
#>  6        2 x      14  
#>  7        1 y      23  
#>  8        1 y      25  
#>  9        1 y      22.5
#> 10        1 y      21.2
#> 11        2 y      20
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: The average of 13 and 14 is not 13

Comment: Thanks @onyambu - I misread the question, I fixed the answer to reflect the desired output.